# How to create a get-graphql-schema enum from Hasura?

Tags: enums, graphql, hasura

I am working on [a project](https://github.com/MetaFam/TheGame) which is backed by Hasura. I am having difficulty creating an `enum` and getting it to auto-generate the values.

I've successfully [created a migration](https://github.com/MetaFam/TheGame/blob/%40mymeta/colored-personality/hasura/migrations/1614544655501_create-mtg-colors-table/up.sql#L1-L12) according to the [enum spec](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/enums.html#enums-in-the-hasura-graphql-engine), and verified it is loading values into the database. Next I ran `yarn hasura console`, and from the console started tracking both tables I created & set `BaseColor` to be an enum type. I added a permission for public to `SELECT` from `BaseColor`.

Next I ran `yarn hasura metadata export`. That generated a tables.yml with [`BaseColor`'s table definition having `is_enum` `true`](https://github.com/MetaFam/TheGame/blob/%40mymeta/colored-personality/hasura/metadata/tables.yaml#L7-L8).

Then I ran, `yarn update-schema` (i.e. `get-graphql-schema http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql > schema.graphql`). The generated file is missing the `BaseColor_enum` I would expect to be present for an enum.

Answer (score 0):

`get-graphql-schema` only generates an `_enum` for a table if that table is referenced by another.

So, if I add a foreign key that references `BaseColor`, it will generate `BaseColor_enum`, otherwise it won't.